# Error: Call to a possibly undefined method startTest

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I'm new to flash development. I got an actionscript (3.0) code to work with, which I'm trying to compile using mxmlc.exe

```
import flash.display.*;

startTest();

function startTest() {
     // Create objects to other classes to start display
}
```

When I compile it with the below command

```
mxmlc.exe Main.mxml
```

Where the above .as file is included, I keep getting the following error

```
Error: Call to a possibly undefined method startTest.
```

There in no class or package is defined in the .as file.
Please provide some inputs here.

Comment: try giving the function a return type, i.e. `function startTest():void{...`

Comment: you talk about .as file but you are compiling Main.mxml... please explain better what are you doing

Comment: The .as file is included in .mxml as

    <fx:Script source="Main.as"/>

Comment: There's no such thing as method calls within a fx:Script, those defined method have to respond to an action such as an event like ADDEDTOSTAGE for example. Those method should also be defined with access modifier such as protected, not defining an access modifier defaults to internal which might not be the proper modifier you are looking for.

Comment: Please show the whole file.